# Get response returning enum value rather than enum text

Tags: c#, angularjs, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-web-api

I have the following `LINQ` query that I am calling from a `Web API`. When I break on the query and check the values, AlertType shows the string value of the `Enum`. When I check the response in the browser, alertType shows the int value of the enum. Can anyone tell me whats going on here?

```
[Route("api/Alert/GetAlertsByUser")]
public async Task<List<AlertConfigVM>> GetAlertsByUser()
{
    try
    {
        var user = await securityService.GetUser(User.Identity.Name);
        return await service.GetAlertsByUser(user.Id);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ErrorHandler.ProcessApiError(ex);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Here is the linq query

```
async public Task<List<AlertConfigVM>> GetAlertsByUser(string userId)
{
    using (var ctx = new JudgePortalContext())
    {
        var query = ctx.UserAlerts.Include(x=>x.DocumentType).Where(x => x.UserId == userId).ToList();
        var alerts = query.Select(u => new AlertConfigVM
        {
            UserId = u.UserId,
            Destination = u.AlertDestination,
            AlertType =  (AlertTypes)u.TypeofAlert,
            HourInterval = u.IntervalAsHours,
            DocumentTypeName= u.DocumentType?.Name??string.Empty
        }).ToList();

        return alerts;
    }
}
```

Here is the return type and the enum

```
public enum AlertTypes
{
    Email=0,
    Text =1
}

public class AlertConfigVM
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
    public AlertTypes AlertType { get; set; }
    public string Destination { get; set; }
    public int? DocumentTypeId { get; set; }
    public string DocumentTypeName { get; set; }
    public int? HourInterval { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I do not see Web API in your code. Could you elaborate more?

Comment: debugger displays the string form of it while when it is sent back to browser it is int, as your enum is inheriting from int

Comment: I am passing the data to my front end via Angular. How would you get around this? @Win see the updated code.

Comment: Ideally, you do not want enum in ViewModel. Does it work if you use string, int or int??

Comment: @Win If i change the type to a string and cast the enum value to a string then the browser gets the correct thing. I designed it as enum because that property will also correspond to a dropdownlist display and value and that seemed like the correct way.

Comment: @Rickjames The issue of enum is *default* ModelBinder might not be able to bind enum on post back. As the result, it throws runtime exceptions. It is why we try to avoid using Enum in ViewModel.